# Getting a “permission denied” when running a Python script to overwrite host file

Tags: python

When I am running a Python script to edit the host file, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File"/Users/tom/Documents/Udemy/Python Mega Course/Website_Blocker_App3.py", line 15, in <module>     with open( host_path, 'r+') as file: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/hosts'
```

I have a Mac OS X and I already tried enabling root user privileges, but it doesn’t seem to be working.

Comment: is it writable?

Comment: I get permission denied when the file in question is open.

Comment: How are you "enabling root privileges". The way you do it matters.

Comment: I am enabling root privileges by going to the command terminal and using the 'dsenable' method.

Comment: this seems to be an issue with my mac but not anything to do with the python script itself